# How do I implement draw with p5,js and instance Containers

Tags: html, css, function, flexbox, p5.js

I am working on a project where I am displaying multiple p5.js projects within a single flexbox in a dropdown tab. I have got to the stage where I've got 2 canvases drawn and in a flex row. I can edit the size of the canvass, change the colour, etc within the setup. My issue is getting the p.draw function to work. I need to input my code after the setup, but my canvas disappears when I try to add the draw function. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Here is the current iteration of my code:

```
<div id="p5-2" class="flex-item">
<script>
            // script 2
            let sketch2 = function(p) {
                p.setup = function() {
                    p.createCanvas(100, 100);
                    p.background("orange");
                }

//The p.draw function should in theory be positioned here

            };
            let node2 = document.createElement('div');
            window.document.getElementById('p5-2').appendChild(node2);
            new p5(sketch2, node2);

            // script 3
        </script>
    </div> 
    <div id="p5-3" class="flex-item">
        <script>
            var sketch3 = function(p) {
                p.setup = function() {
                    p.createCanvas(100, 100);
                    p.background("green");
                }
//The p.draw function should in theory be positioned here

            };
            let node3 = document.createElement('div');
            window.document.getElementById('p5-3').appendChild(node3);
            new p5(sketch3, node3);
        </script>
```

Comment: *I need to input my code after the setup, but my canvas disappears when I try to add the draw function* It's been a while since i last used p5 But isn't there a **setup function** where you do all your housekeeping stuff before beginning the draw ?

Comment: When working with instance containers, its a bit different. The set-up is written as p.setup =function(){.......